# Social Post URL redirects to user's personal Facebook messages, not the Connected Social Account's Messages

Tags: url, facebook, socialpost

When a user clicks on a social post that was created by an inbox message, it redirects to the user's personal Facebook messages page.

We expect the URL to open the messages page for the managed page, not the personal user's messages.

Any workaround that may be possible, both within Facebook or Salesforce, to ensure that the user lands at the correct page?

Comment: https://screencast.com/t/PpThRMuj8T